# Jetbrains Space shellScript variables

Tags: jetbrains-space-automation, jetbrains-space

I'm trying to use bash variables in a shellScript in jetbrains space automation to no success.

My .space.kts is as follows;

```
job("mvn compile"){
    container(displayName="mvn", image="maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17"){

        shellScript {
            content = """
                FOO="bar"
                echo $FOO
            """
        }
    }
}
```

in the above i'd expect "bar" to be echoed, but instead im getting the following error when this tries to run;

```
Dsl file '/tmp/16487320722162400386/.space.kts' downloaded in 1736 ms
Compiling DSL script /tmp/16487320722162400386/.space.kts...
downloading /home/pipelines-config-dsl-compile-container/space-automation-runtime.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jetbrains#space-automation-runtime;1.1.100932!space-automation-runtime.jar (71ms)
Compilation failed in 8.652797664s.
ERROR Unresolved reference: FOO (.space.kts:9:23)
Cleaned up the output folder: /tmp/16487320722162400386
DSL processing failed: Compilation exited with non zero exit code: 2. Exit code: 102
```

I had planned on parsing the branch name from `JB_SPACE_GIT_BRANCH` and storing it in a variable to use in a call to mvn to build and tag a container using Jib

Is there anyway that i can use variables within the content of a shellScript? or should/ can this be done in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace $ by ${"$"}:

```
job("mvn compile") {
  container(displayName="mvn", image="maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17") {
      shellScript {
          content = """
              FOO="bar"
              echo ${"$"}FOO
          """
      }
  }
}
```

Or use a sh file file.sh like this:

```
FOO="bar"
echo $FOO
```

.

```
job("mvn compile") {
  container(displayName="mvn", image="maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17") {
      shellScript {
          content = """
              ./file.sh
          """
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Single quotes are also possible within the {}

Comment: If you just want to reference an external script file, you can use the `location` property (with a path) instead of `content`, so there is no intermediate generated script file